# Proving that the polish notation has unique readability

Tags: logic, proof-techniques, propositional-logic, induction

I am familiar with the polish notation when it comes to algorithmically reading phrases, but I am having a hard time proving the following exercise:

> K is a function so that 1) $K(*)$ is an integer if $*$ is a symbol of a language, 2) if $\sigma = \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \dots \sigma_n$ is a phrase of the language, then $K(\sigma) = K(\sigma_1) + K(\sigma_2) + \dots + K(\sigma_n)$, where $\sigma_i$ is a symbol of the alphabet and 3) if $\phi$ is a propositional formula, then $K(\phi)=1$.
> If the last part of a propositional formula is a conjuction of one or more propositional formulas, and the genuine first part is not, then prove that the polish notation has unique readability.

I am having trouble understanding how to solve this. I believe it is with induction, so I started by saying that if $\phi_1$ is of length 1, then it also has $K(\phi_1)=1$ and is uniquely readable. Then supposing that if it's of length $k$ it is uniquely readable, I should prove that it's the same with $k+1$. So supposing that we add a a symbol to the phrase and it becomes $O \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \dots \sigma_k$, according to rules we know that $K(O\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \dots \sigma_k) = K(O) + K(\sigma_1) + \dots + K(\sigma_k)$ and there are two cases:

1. either it's equal to 1, in which case it is a propositional variable and is uniquely readable, or
2. the value is greater than one (since all $K(*)$ are integer).

I am not sure how to continue with the 2nd case and finish the proof. I am sure that - if I'm correct in my thinking - I have to use the "first and last part" rules of the exercise.

I want to note, that I believe putting $O$ in either side of the phrase has a similar explanation or at the very least if it's different I can think about it after having understood the above first.

If my thinking process is wrong, how else can I approach this?

Comment: These proofs are usually done by induction on well-formed formulas.